# Cannot login to my school website

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to use a python script (specifically requests) for logging into my university account and having the program do what I need it to do. I used the following code to try logging into the website:

```
import requests
import time

url = 'https://myschool.edu/'

next_url = 'https://mynextpage.edu/'
login_data = {"j_username":'input username here', "j_password":'input password here'}


with requests.Session() as s:
    s.get(url)
    p = s.post(url, data=login_data)
    # print the html returned or something more intelligent to see if it's a successful login page.
    print p.text
    time.sleep(40)

    # An authorised request.
    r = s.get(next_url)
    print r.text
```

When I have p.text print out, all I see is the html to the original login
page. I don't understand what I am typing wrong about this. Thanks for all your help!!

Comment: Can you show the start tag for form? Currently there's only `</form>`, but it's missing the start tag.

Comment: you might be missing fields... csrf token etc... check that on browser network tab in inspect element :)

Comment: I ended up showing the whole html code with it some parts blocking the information about my university. Sorry, it may look sloppy compared to what I was trying it make it look like

Comment: You need to include all inputs to your post data and send it to form["action"]

Comment: Could you explain what all the inputs are (I thought it was only username and password) and also, how would I send it (programming wise) to the form[action]? Thanks for your help!

Comment: 1). To interact with javascript, you may need http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/; 2). Figure out how which url does the javascript POST to, and post your credential to that url directly in Python. But then you need to manipulate the session/cookie kind of stuff, could be a hassle. Maybe just let the browser deal with it via Selenium and use the first approach.

Comment: You're right, it's only 'j_username' and 'j_password' . The form 'action' is the string inside <form action=""> in your html, it's where the data get submitted . You need to post `login_data` to `url + form[action]` , however @zyxue may be right, you may have to use selenium for this site.

Comment: ok, so zyxue is the best answer. I ended up using selinium (awesome library by the way) and ended up getting what I wanted to do working now. Now my only issue is how do I say that he was the accepted answer? I don't see a check mark on my page, and I don't want to click "answer your question", because that seems like I'm giving nobody credit for doing that. Thanks guys for all your great help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Goes with http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/, and let the browser handle most of the heavy liftings.
2. If you indeed want to interact with the server directly in Python, you may end up dealing with session/cookie/credential kind of stuff, which could be a hassle.

1 feels like programming while 2 is more like hacking. ;)